# Sweep equivalent in Julia

Tags: julia, data-manipulation

From R documentation:

> `sweep`: Return an array obtained from an input array by sweeping out a summary
>   statistic.

For example, here is how I divide each row by its row sum:

```
> rs = rowSums(attitude)
> ratios = sweep(attitude, 1, rs, FUN="/")
> head(ratios)
     rating complaints privileges  learning    raises  critical    advance
1 0.1191136  0.1412742 0.08310249 0.1080332 0.1689751 0.2548476 0.12465374
2 0.1518072  0.1542169 0.12289157 0.1301205 0.1518072 0.1759036 0.11325301
3 0.1454918  0.1434426 0.13934426 0.1413934 0.1557377 0.1762295 0.09836066
4 0.1568123  0.1619537 0.11568123 0.1208226 0.1388175 0.2159383 0.08997429
5 0.1680498  0.1618257 0.11618257 0.1369295 0.1473029 0.1721992 0.09751037
6 0.1310976  0.1676829 0.14939024 0.1341463 0.1646341 0.1493902 0.10365854
> rowSums(ratios) # check that ratios sum up to 1
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

My attempt in Julia:

```
x = rand(3, 4)
x[1, 1] = 10
x[2, 1] = 20
x[3, 1] = 30
rowsum = sum(x, 2)
rowsum_mat = repmat(rowsum, 1, size(x, 2))
x = x ./ rowsum_mat
```

This works but is clunky. Is there a more elegant and efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Removing R tag. Sweep operator is not specific to R.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No need to use `repmat` — all of Julia's `.`-operators do ["broadcasting"](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/arrays/#broadcasting) by default. This means it matches the dimensions of the two arguments and then expands any dimensions that have length 1 (the singleton dimensions) to match the other array.  Since reductions keep the same dimensionality of the source array, they can be used directly with any dot-operator.

In your case, you can just use:

```
x ./ sum(x, 2)
```

since:

```
julia> x ./ rowsum_mat == x ./ rowsum
true
```